# Pasar str a formato fecha en python

Tags: python, spyder

Estoy convirtiendo de str a date una columna de un dataframe de fechas, donde estoy utilizando el siguiente código para ello, ya que el formato fecha que yo creía que había es 2018-05-13:

```
datetime.strptime(embebido_equipart.iloc[i]['primerPartido'],"%Y-%m-%d")
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero me salto un error de que en la misma columna existen varios formatos de fecha, como 10/05/2020. ¿Habría alguna forma de cambiar todas las fechas de una misma vez aunque tengan diferente formato?

Al tener varios formatos diferentes mezclados en una misma columna me complica el cambiarlo de una vez, y no sabría bien como hacerlo.

El error que me salto es el siguiente, donde me dice que el formato que he elegido no es el correcto:

```
time data '21/04/1900' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías crear una función que intente transformar en todos los formatos que desees. Cachar la excepción y continuar hasta verificar que uno de los formatos coincide. Si ninguno coincide, entonces lanzar la excepción.

```
from datetime import datetime

def transform_date(date_string, date_formats):
    for dformat in date_formats:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(date_string, dformat)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError("Any format is not valid.")
    

dates = [
    '1999-06-21',
    '01/06/2020'
]

date_formats = [
    '%Y-%m-%d',
    '%d/%m/%Y'
]

for date in dates:
    date_transformed = transform_date(date, date_formats)
    print(f"La fecha {date} fue transformada a {type(date_transformed)} y se puede comprobar imprimiento en el formato que yo quiera {date_transformed.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}")
```

Comment: Perfecto, al crear esa función ya me deja realizar la conversión de forma correcta. Muchas gracias!!!